# Is "Reason to Believe" correct that the Jewish Nation had no outstanding achievements?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, king-david, king-solomon

[R Gottlieb](https://www.dovidgottlieb.com/) in his book called [Reason to Believe](https://mosaicapress.com/product/reason-to-believe/) claims that the UNEXPECTED survival of the Jews is a reason to believe in a Supernatural Being that cares about the Jews, has abilities to affect the world etc. He claims that that the Jews did not have any major successes (eg outstanding accomplishments in math, art etc) that could EXPLAIN their survival - see there for more details of this argument.

My Q on this: What about the unparalleled wisdom and extraordinary wealth and unique talents of Shlomo Ha'melech?

(It's possible to answer that Shlomo did not rule for a historically significant amount of time, but the reason why I'm not comfortable with that answer is because when R Gottlieb deals with the SIZE of the EMPIRE of David and Shlomo (in the footnote on page 202), he does NOT use that logic, so I was assuming that he feels that he does NOT need to rely on a partial "giving in" like that).

Comment: Indeed shlomo hamelech was the most wise man. Perhaps R Gotlieb was reffering to most of history, not in the times of shlomo. Shlomos rule was only 40 years. That's not much of an explanation of the over thousands of years, of the survival of the jews.

Comment: After reading your question, I listened to a video lecture by Rabbi Gottlieb on YouTube discussing the book. At least from how it sounded in the video, I think you may be misunderstanding what he wrote. It was about an hour talk.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Shlomy I agree to your logic. The reason why I didn't suggest that answer is because when R Gottlieb deals with the SIZE of the EMPIRE of David and Shlomo, he does NOT use that logic, so I was assuming that he feels that he does NOT need to rely on a partial "giving in" like that.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Can you please provide a link to the youtube video, and can you also please explain to me how YOU understood R Gottleib?

Comment: It's not clear to me that this question is about Judaism, rather than history of the Jews. It may be helpful to clarify what context R' Gottlieb claims an absence of Jewish accomplishment in. If it's a historical era, then corroboration of that claim seems to be about history and not Judaism per se. If the question is about understanding R' Gottlieb's claims about Jewish faith, please [edit] it accordingly.

Comment: Correct. Please see [this Help Center entry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the official description of our scope.

Comment: No worries! The post will wait patiently. Have a good Shabbos.

Comment: @TzviK Per your request: https://youtu.be/MjGMmoZGQpg

Comment: @yaacovdeane Thank you. I will have a look when I get the chance.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I have edited my question to [hopefully] be phrased as a question on R Gottlieb's views on Judaism. Please let me know if this edited version is appropriate for this site.

Comment: Thanks. I've reopened the post.

Comment: How would Shlomo Hamelech's wisdom EXPLAIN their survival? I don't see the problem.

Comment: @N.T. If I remember correctly, R Gottlieb says that a potential reason why the Jews survived is perhaps other people joined the Jewish nation because of its achievements. See there for more details.